# man snapcraft gives nothing

Tags: release-management, snap, documentation, manpage

Is there no manual page for the 'snapcraft' command or is my installation broken?

I'd sure like to read more about 'snapcraft release [myproject] 1 candidate'.  Once I release a candidate, how do I go test that?  I have no idea.  I published a snap a while ago, but I don't know what that means.  It doesn't show up in any store or anywhere that I can see it online.  Is this all documented somewhere that I've just simply overlooked?

Answer (score 2):

There are no `man` pages in the `snapcraft` package unfortunately. Help is contained with:

1. The command `snapcraft -h` which displays quite comprehensive assistance. To get a permanent, more easily readable version of this document perhaps run the following command in a Terminal window for a copy on your Desktop:
    `snapcraft -h > ~/Desktop/snapcraft_help`
2. An address given at the base of the information above which also contains *very* comprehensive assistance, (including [publishing your snap](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/upload-your-snap/) which you mentioned in your question):

   - [Build Apps | Ubuntu Developer Portal](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/)

Man pages and comprehensive documentation *with the package* would be nice mind you....

**References:**

- [File list of package snapcraft in xenial of architecture all](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/snapcraft/filelist)

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know how to add a man page to my own package, but I do have a help menu item that is supposed to bring up the default browser at the webpage where help on the app is documented.  Unfortunately, launching the default browser is outside the security constraints of an installed snap, as far as I can tell.